# solving the game of fiver

Tags: mathematical-optimization, warning-messages

Up to an error by myself, the following code is an implementation of the mixed integer linear programming of the game of Fiver :

```
(*Fonction objectif*)
obj = {Total[Total[Table[x[i, j], {i, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 5}]]]};
(*Contrainte sur les cases d'angles*)
cca = Join[{x[1, 1] + x[2, 1] + x[1, 2] - 2 y[1, 1] == 
     1}, {x[5, 1] + x[4, 1] + x[5, 2] - 2* y[5, 1] == 
     1}, {x[5, 1] + x[4, 1] + x[5, 2] - 2 y[5, 1] == 
     1}, {x[1, 5] + x[2, 5] + x[1, 4] - 2* y[1, 5] == 
     1}, {x[5, 5] + x[4, 5] + x[5, 4] - 2 y[5, 5] == 1}];
(*Contrainte sur les cases centrales*)
ccc = Flatten@
   Table[x[i, j] + x[i - 1, j] + x[i + 1, j] + x[i, j - 1] + 
      x[i, j + 1] - 2 *y[i, j] == 1, {i, 2, 4}, {j, 2, 4}];
(*Contraintes sur les cases de la première colonne*)
ccpq = Flatten@
   Table[x[i, 1] + x[i - 1, 1] + x[i + 1, j] + x[i, 2] - 2 *y[i, 1] ==
      1, {i, 2, 4}];
(*Contraintes sur les cases de la cinquième colonne*)
cccq = Flatten@
   Table[x[i, 5] + x[i - 1, 5] + x[i + 1, 5] + x[i, 4] - 2* y[i, 5] ==
      1, {i, 2, 4}];
(*Contraintes sur les cases de la première ligne*)
ccpl = Flatten@
   Table[x[1, j] + x[i, j - 1] + x[1, j + 1] + x[2, j] - 2 *y[i, 5] ==
      1, {i, 2, 4}];
(*contraintes sur les cases de la cinquième ligne*)
cccl = Flatten@
   Table[x[5, j] + x[5, j - 1] + x[5, j + 1] + x[4, j] - 2 *y[5, j] ==
      1, {j, 2, 4}];
(*contraintes quantitatives sur les cases centrales*)
cic1 = Flatten@Table[1 <= x[i, j] <= 5, {i, 2, 4}, {j, 2, 4}];
(*contraintes quantitatives sur les cases de frontière*)
cipq1 = Flatten@Table[1 <= x[i, 1] <= 3, {i, 1, 5}];
cicq1 = Flatten@Table[1 <= x[i, 5] <= 3, {i, 1, 5}];
cipl1 = Flatten@Table[1 <= x[1, j] <= 3, {j, 2, 4}];
cicl1 = Flatten@Table[1 <= x[5, j] <= 3, {j, 2, 4}];
obj1 = Join[obj, cca, ccc, ccpq, cccq, ccpl, cccl, cic1, cicq1, cipl1,
    cicl1];
(*nom des variables*)
var1 = Flatten[Table[x[i, j], {i, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 5}]];
var2 = Flatten[Table[y[i, j], {i, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 5}]];
var = Join[var1, var2];
NMinimize[obj1, var \[Element] Integers]
```

Unfortunately NMinimize complains that the constraints are not valid. Could some one help me to find my error ?

Comment: I guess the problem lies in several symbolic `j`s like in `x[3, -1 + j]` lingering around the constraints.

Comment: Moreover, if this is a linear programming problem, it might be worthwhile to reformulate it in some kind of standard form that `LinearProgramming` can handle. But maybe `NMinimize` does that automatically. Hm. After studiying [this toturial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalOptimization.html), I conclude that it does not.

Comment: Thanks Henrik. I was persuaded that NMinimize was able to do that. I will try LinearProgramming. But it seems that FindMinimum do the trick.